# Altium create negative text on polygon/fill

Tags: altium

I need to add some text to my PCB and put it on polygon part. I can do this but only as a layer but I need to have my text as negative(non copper) layer. Anybody knows how do the trick? It's like polygon cutout but need it for text.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Altium at all but Eagle provides a "restrict" layer, which overrides any copper pours in the area. Is there something similar in Altium?

Answer (score 6):

Here is at least one way to do it:

Place a rectangular cutout in your polygon pour.

Create your text string on the target copper layer using "Inverted" and "Use inverted Rectangle" check boxes. Edit the size width/height to be slightly larger than your cutout. Drop the rectangle over the cutout making sure that it overlaps completely.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Such an approach would lead to clearance rule violation.
Change Text/Poly clearance rule to '-2' and polygon pour cutout will not be required.